# Laurent Series Expansion Solution Verification

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

Write the Laurent Series of
$$ \frac{1}{z(1-z)^2}$$

Now the singularities are $z=0$ and $z=1$.

My attempt:

For $z=0$ case
$$= \frac{1}{z}.(1-z)^{-2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{z}.[1+2z+3z^2+...]$$

For $z=1$ case
$$=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}.\frac{1}{(1+z-1)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}.(1+(z-1))^{-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}.[1+(z-1)+(z-1)^2+(z-1)^3+...]$$

I used the $(1+x)^{-n}$ expansion in the last line.

Am I doing it right? Is there a better approach?

Comment: That's how I would have done it.

Comment: You are assuming that $|z|<1$ in the first case and that $|z-1|<1$ in the second case, which makes your solution incomplete. You need to consider also the domains defined by $|z|>1$ in the first case and that $|z-1|>1$.

Comment: The expansion of $(1+u)^{-1}$ has alternating signs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses partial fraction decomposition:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z(1-z)^2} 
&= \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n + \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1} z^n \\
&= \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n \ge 0} (n+2) z^n
\end{align}